# Перекрытие ссылки и INPUT

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, прошу помощи! Имеется слайдер (CodaSlider) и ниже строчки с *INPUT`ами*, при пролистывании слайдера происходит то ли активность инпута то ли курсор устанавливается на него, короче сам инпут подсвечивается, это можно увидеть когда будете листать слайдер. Вот [сюда](http://jsfiddle.net/vXjaa/) свалил пример.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Да и еще я пытался ковырять скрипт ***coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js***, там же в jsFiddle он прикручен в *External Resources*.

Вот в этом куске (*Create the Tabs*) я добавил **"z"**

> `<a href='#" + (n+1) + "z" + "'>`

```
// Create the Tabs
            jQuery(this).before("<div class='stripNav' id='stripNav" + j + "'><ul><\/ul><\/div>");
            jQuery(this).find("div.panel").each(function(n) {
                        jQuery("div#stripNav" + j + " ul").append("<li class='tab" + (n+1) + "'><a href='#" + (n+1) + "z" + "'>" + jQuery(this).attr("title") + "<\/a><\/li>");                                             
            });
```

инпуты перестали активироваться, но свалился автоскроллинг.

Там еще у каждого инпута имеется ID, если ID убрать то проблема решиться, но увы их убирать нельзя, должна сохраниться нумерация (обязательно).

Comment: Ковырять такое -- вы смелый человек.

    o.7("p.O").1k();o.q("T").l("1l");b m=o.7("4.I").C();b k=o.7("4.I").1m();b U=m*k;o.7("4.t").K("C",U);b N=k*2;F(h.g&&D(h.g.s(1))<=k){b 9=D(h.g.s(1));b e=-(m*(9-1));3(6).7("4.t").K({H:e})}B{b 9=1};o.w(d(i){3(6).W("<4 r=\'J\' M=\'J"+j+"\'><a A=\'#\'>1n</a><\\/4>");3(6).1o("<4 r=\'L\';

Comment: @Олег Б ... а, что делать, тяжела и неказиста жизнь простого... сами знаете кого )

Comment: у вас там генерируются ссылки (которые для галереи) типа `<a href="#3" class="">THIRD</a>`

неудивительно что после клика на такую ссылку он переходит на #3 :) ну и ещё у вас там в этих инпутах ошибки в верстке, <p> не закрыт, в одном месте </br>, остальные <br> не закрыты в виде <br/>

возьмите  другой слайдер, их мало что-ли ?